# Edit was already approved? Then let me review the next!

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, review

When using the Beta Review tool, if you act on a suggested edit too late, you are presented with this box:

[image: Review Error]

If I click on the link (as directed) to correct the post, I am taken out of the review queue altogether. In this particular instance, I was trying to reject the edit as too minor. Since it was still technically correct and already approved, I felt no need to actually do this.

Unfortunately, the alternative, clicking on the box to dismiss (as *also* directed -- two conflicting instructions here), leaves me at the same review. This makes it cumbersome (though not impossible) to move on to the next review.

For the purposes of responding to this message box:

- When dismissing the box, it would be better to **dismiss *and* move to the next review.**
- When clicking on the link to improve it, I'd say **leave that functionality as-is**.

Anyone else agree?

Comment: If you want to reject an edit, and it has already been approved, one might want to roll back the edit.  Here I probably wouldn't as it's just too minor, but it was a more problematic edit I wouldn't just want to move on.

Comment: @Servy Absolutely agree. The box as it is allows for 2 options: Edit the post, *or* dismiss the box. I'm saying that the dismiss option should be improved.

Comment: At the very least the [Next] button should appear, allowing you to ignore the popup. (It did appear after I found this question and then clicked back to the review page, so I clicked forward to comment.)

Answer (score 4):

I think it makes sense to show a notification if your action is different than what already happened to the post. For example, if x number of users have already rejected the post and you try to approve it after the fact, it should let you know what happened instead of just sending you to the next review. This way you will be informed of how your suggestions are differing from other users. I agree that there should be some way to go to the next post when dismissing the notification, but I'm not sure it should be the default action.

However, I have noticed that when the suggested edit has already been *rejected*, if you try to reject it then it will still give you the reject pop-up message instead of sending you to the next one. This seems to be a waste of time since the post has already been rejected. I would suggest correcting that action.

Comment: I agree the notification should stay, particularly when a horrible/incorrect edit was approved, etc. Basically, if the system is smart enough to tell me I can't take an action on the suggested edit, then it should be smart enough to move on once I've acknowledged the situation.