# edit review queue, edit accepted while improving

Tags: bug, review, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Improving a suggested edit that has been approved in the meantime leads to a dead end](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145565/improving-a-suggested-edit-that-has-been-approved-in-the-meantime-leads-to-a-dea)
>   [The robo-approvers are killing my will to review edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155561/the-robo-approvers-are-killing-my-will-to-review-edits)

So I was going through the Edit queue just now, and I came across [This edit suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1164933)

Now the paragraph changes at the top did make the post more readable, BUT it caused some of the code to be left out of code blocks, so I clicked `Improve` (after further investigation, that happened because another edit fixed the code blocks, apparently while the suggester was composing her edit, and the suggested edit over-wrote that edit.)

I got the code elements back into the code block, but I got the following error when submitting the edit:

[image]

Now, It appears as though the suggested edit got approved while I was in there editing the edit.  After looking at the suggestion log, and the edit log, there's nothing to indicate to me that anyone else made any changes before I did.

I suspect that this is not desired behavior, considering that my edit was an amendment to Karin's suggested edit.  I propose that the `improve` feature be treated as such, and not be forced to compete with the specific edit suggestion that it's improving.

Comment: @animuson i try to briefly look for duplicates before I ask, but due to variant verbage among other things it's hard to find them most of the time

Comment: @KateGregory although one of the issues raised by that rant is this one, it is a different kind of post.  animuson's linked post actually is similar to this one however

Answer (score 1):

This happens some times.

Edits are recorded as reviews when you save them. So it is possible that other users have reviewed the post.

The good part is that the edit still counts, so the post is (hopefully) improved which is the ultimate goal of the review system.

Just keep up the good work, and in the end you will be rewarded.

The fun part is that the frequency has decreased since the threshold of 20 was introduced. Probably because editing does not give you extra reviews anymore.

Comment: the problem is that the "improved" edit doesn't actually get  applied in this case.  Now I was able to go edit the post after the fact, and redo the edit, but that's an un-necessary hoop