# Did I just review a suggested edit all by myself?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits, review-audits

I recently rejected a [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1441351) and then wanted to see if others did the same or if it was approved, so I found it in "History" and it said:

[image: Review audit passed 22 mins ago: Lev Levitsky reviewed this 22 mins ago: Reject]

At first I thought that it just meant no one had reviewed it after me, but I seem to recall seeing a more informative message in the past, like "This edit needs more reviews".

To date, I believe, every edit needed 3 reviews on SO. Did it change recently? Or is it a reputation thing?

P.S. Sorry if's another dupe, searching Meta is a skill I haven't yet mastered apparently.

EDIT: it was just a test, wasn't it? That's what the "audit" word means. But where's the [congratulation message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157121/181223)? Don't suggested edits have one?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-_IlNbsILLE

Comment: @balpha Yeah thanks :) For a minute there I thought the system decided I was so cool I earned triple-weight reviews. But at least I didn't fail, it's something.

Comment: There are no congratulations...there's only intolerable pain and suffering if you fail...

Comment: @Bart But not in other queues? That's not fair. Edit: the message I linked to is not for the review, it's for feedback, so maybe it _is_ fair.

Comment: Hybrid of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165924/is-there-supposed-to-be-feedback-on-edit-review-audits and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165719/does-improve-allow-an-edit-approver-to-be-a-majority-of-1-and-must-we-start-to

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The suggested edit you rejected is not really a suggested edit in the queue.  It was a [review audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/review-audits/info) to make sure you are reviewing correctly.  That's why it appears as if you rejected it by yourself.

But you actually do have the ability to reject or approve audits by yourself since you have full edit capabilities.  You were to click "Improve" instead of "Reject" or "Accept", you will be able to make additional changes to the edit.  Once you submit the edit, it will automatically approve or reject the suggested edit depending on whether or not you checked the "Suggested Edit was helpful" box.

However in the edit history, the [Community](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) user will actually be the one accepting or rejecting the edit.

Comment: And of course I realized it seconds after posting the question :)

Comment: To your update: that's a way to approve by myself, but I can't easily reject edits like that, can I?

Comment: @LevLevitsky absolutely you can.  When you improve the edit, you can uncheck the "The suggested edit was helpful" box and when you do that, it will reject the original suggested edit.

Comment: But the question is always opened in the edited state, so I have to manually undo the changes, right?

Comment: @LevLevitsky yes, but usually if it is a bad edit that needs undone, you would generally reject and go back and edit yourself unless the bad edit was easy enough to undo.  I tend to reserve the Improve-rejection for edits that extremely minor and do not go far enough, and I have to make significant improvements beyond was what suggested.